# How do you implement the jQuery noConflict() method correctly?

Tags: javascript, mootools, jquery

I can't get the `noConflict()` method to work properly. I've been searching online for hours and can't seem to get a solid answer. Here's what I have in my header...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slimbox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script><!-- jQuery script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/page_scroll.js"></script><!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- jQuery easing plug-in -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    // Use jQuery via $j(...)
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j("div").hide();
    });

    // Use Mootools with $(...), etc.
    $('someid').hide();
</script>
```

There's no other jQuery or JavaScript within my HTML (just what I have externally), so "placing anything that uses the `$` variable in the `noConlict` method" is not an option.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is have slimbox and easing page scroll (for my navigation) to work together. The problem is of course one works when the other is removed and vice versa. Also, when I use the `noConflict()` method I get slimbox to work and not pagescroll, but when I remove the `noConflict()` method I get pagescroll to work and not slimbox. So apperently `noConflict` is doing something, I just don't know what that is or how to go about it.

If anyone can help me out, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: who edited the problem out of the problem? there's nothing wrong with jquery, the mootools code was invalid. Granted I know nothing of mooTools, but $(id).setStyle('display', 'none');  instead of hide() worked fine...

Comment: @Purmou I think you got a little overzealous in your editing... The script tags were/are important to the question. The problem revolves around loading plugins with multiple frameworks that bind to `$`. One of the plugins is doing something wrong... Now the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why load less when you can load moar. Maybe load prototype, YUI and Dojo too.

Comment: @32bitkid: Good point, I WAS a bit over the edge. Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 1):

when using other js libs that leverage the $ alias,
I have found reliable results by using

```
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // your jQuery code here i.e. 

  // jQuery('some-selector-expression').somefunction();

});

// prototype or mootools code that uses the $ alias works fine here
```

Answer (score 0):

So are you saying it does not work when you declare $j? You can define your own alternate names (e.g. jq, $J, awesomeQuery - anything you want). Try calling it something w/o the $

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // function here...
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Seeing the exact code might help.